# Plotting lifetables, incidence with varying denominators

Tags: survival, poisson-regression, mortality

I have data in the following format:

```
id yrdx yrsrv dead
1  2000 3     1
2  2003 10    0
3  2004 5     0
4  2007 1     1
```

where `yrdx` indicates the year of diagnosis for a disease, `yrsrv` indicates how long an individual survived, and `dead` indicates whether or not they died or were censored.

I would like to plot death rates in this varying population over calendar time. The issue is that some individuals are censored. Post-estimating the results from a cox model is not possible since 1) I aim to estimate the effects of time *explicitly* and 2) the time free model has no other covariates, so the Cox model won't converge.

I understand there is a way to do this with a Poisson regression model using years of survival as an offset.

The linear model is something like:

$$\log \left( \frac{\mu}{t} \right) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \mbox{year}$$

I get confused because we are modeling time in two ways, once it is constrained to account for the denominator, or risk time.

1. Is my model formulation correct?
2. How exactly does this (or the correct model) account for censored data and risk sets explicitly over time?
3. Do I need to aggregate these data into a more complicated lifetable format? If so, how to do this in R?